# Changing the second argument in setFont() does not change font size - reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, fonts, font-size, reportlab

My canvas initialization looks like:

```
canvas = canvas.Canvas(save_name, pagesize=(4032, 3024), bottomup=1)
#canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 12) #set font size and type (not working)
canvas.setFontSize(10000000) #set pt size (not working)
```

And my drawstring looks like:

```
canvas.drawString(100, y, line)
```

where `y` is a variable and `line` is a string.

No matter what I set either the `setFontSize()` argument to or the second argument in `setFont()`, the size of the font does not change in the PDF.

System: Debian (stretch), Python 3.5.3, Reportlab 3.5.8

EDIT:

Here's that MCVE

```
canvas = canvas.Canvas(save_name, pagesize=(4032, 3024), bottomup=1)
canvas.setFont("Times-Roman", 20)
text = "foo bar"
canvas.drawString(100, 3000, text)
canvas.save()
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. Have you tried it with any other font? Please provide a MCVE (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Note also that I couldn't find any documentation for a `setFontSize()` method in the Reportlab manual.

Comment: @martineau I tried with 'Helvetica' as it is in the first code block, and then with reportlab defaults. No dice. [Here's where I found the documentation for `setFontSize()`](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-reference.pdf).

Comment: I don't see a `reportlab-reference.pdf` manual listed in the [documentation section](https://www.reportlab.com/documentation/)—and `setFontSize()` wasn't like in the ones that are there that I looked at. That's why I ask you to change your question so it included a **complete** snippet that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @martineau While the method was found within `reportlab.pdfgen` and compiled with calling `from reportlab import *` and `from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas`, I changed it to `canvas.setFont("Times-Roman", 20)`, which was a line I copied directly from the first PDF found in your link. The text is still in whatever default font and size it was in before, not being changed. Sorry, this is my first Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Not sure why, but placing the `setFont()` method right before the `drawString()` method fixed it.